# ExpressJs regex in routing

Tags: javascript, regex, express

I am currently trying to create a calculator API using ExpressJs. My problem is using regex as routes to determine common patterns.

A valid typical route is `api/calculator/:operator/:number1/:number2` where by `operator` is a mathematical operator in a string format (add, subtract, multiply, divide) and `number1` and `number2` are operands.

My aim is, if any number is missed in the route, e.g `api/calculator/:operator/:number1/`, or `api/calculator/:operator//:number2` or `api/calculator/:operator//` I want to send a response that the operands are invalid.

Also, if the operator is not valid, a response needs to be sent as a well.

How can I use regex to determine if the route is a valid one?

Comment: Why do you need regex? Just add routes for those? If the operator is not valid, you can check for that in `req.params`.

Comment: My point is to avoid repetition since I have multiple routes. I can simply create a function that takes care of the validation but I do not want to call the function in each and every route that is defined. Hence, I want to create a route that can capture common patterns in the route URL and return a response

Answer (score 0):

In your routing you can use a regex to require at least one char in each of the three params:

```
app.get('api/calculator/:operator(.{1,})/:number1(.{1,})/:number2(.{1,})', (req, res) => { ... });
app.get('api/calculator/*', (req, res) => { ... });
```

The first routing is used for valid patterns, the second routing is used for error reporting

You can also apply a pattern to further restrict the routing, such as alpha only for the operator, and numbers only for the numbers:

```
app.get('api/calculator/:operator([A-Za-z]+)/:number1([+-]?[0-9.]+)/:number2([+-]?[0-9.]+)', (req, res) => { ... });
```

Or, go for more fancy number validation with `([+-]?[0-9]+(\\.[0-9]+)?)`

Comment: I  believe that regex validates to true when the route pattern has the right operator and both operands as digits. How do I now make the regex validate to true when either of the operators is not digits, what would be the pattern?

Comment: @mogale: To route on error you could negate, such as `/:number2([^0-9.+-]+`, however you can't use that for all both numbers because it would be an AND condition, and you'd want an OR. Why not route for what you want, and use a catch-all for the error case as described?

Comment: @mogale: Does that answer your question?

Comment: I tried implementing your approach, but I couldn't get it to work

Answer (score -1):

First Wow this is Just Wrong

> My aim is, if any number is missed in the route, e.g
> `api/calculator/:operator/:number1/`, or
> `api/calculator/:operator//:number2` or `api/calculator/:operator//` I
> want to send a response that the operands are invalid.

If the route is defined you can't interchange them

The thing with express routes is that its Relative in nature
so if a `GET` Route Such as this is called  `api/calculator/:operator/:number1/:number2` as `api/calculator/*/3/3`

the operator would be "+"
and number1 would be "3"
and number2 would be "3"
but in a `GET` Route `api/calculator/*/3` or `api/calculator/*`

the operator would be "+"
and number1 would be "3"
and number2 would be "undefined"

The correct way is to handle it as Express Query

So your code should be like
`api/calculator/?operator="+"&number1="3"&number2="3"`

So this way you can access the query and the application won't crash
when interchange using `req.query.value`

https://expressjs.com/en/api.html#req.query to read more

Comment: I am not sure if you are using an asterisk as a wild card of any string, but my operators are in words format not raw. Does your point still apply in that case?

Comment: Yea even in the raw format I feel like the query option is still the best